# Python how to bubble up exception with full stack information

Tags: python

See the following code

```
def ex_string(ex):
    return "Error:{} Traceback:{}".format(ex, traceback.format_exc())

def map_values(listing):
    ...
    obj = listing['value']
    ...

def process_listing(listing):
    try:
        listing = map_values(listing)
    except Exception as ex:
        do_some_handling(listing)
        print ex_string(ex)  # this stack shows actual line inside map_values
        raise ex

def start():
    for listing in listings:
        try:
            process_listing(listing)
            save_listing(listing)
        except Exception as ex:
            error = ex_string(ex)  #this stack shows map_values function only
            log_error(error)
```

As above, when `listing` does not contain `'value'` element, I don't know which line is causing issue, all I know from log is somewhere inside `map_values` function, how do I get the full stack trace from where the exception was first raised? In this case `obj = listing['value']`

Comment: Just `raise` it, not `raise ex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `raise` with no argument inside an `except` clause to reraise the exception you're handling with its original traceback:

```
def process_listing(listing):
    try:
        listing = map_values(listing)
    except Exception as ex:
        do_some_handling(listing)
        print ex_string(ex)
        raise  # no ex
```

`raise` with no argument means you want the exception you're handling to be considered unhandled, so it resumes propagating with the same traceback.

Using `raise` with one argument here means you're signalling that your *exception handler* has encountered an error, so Python constructs a new stack trace pointing to the `raise` in the exception handler.

Note that `raise` with an argument behaves differently on Python 3, where exceptions record their associated traceback. On Python 3, `raise` and `raise ex` will both preserve the original traceback, but `raise ex` will add an extra record to the traceback for the `raise ex` line.

Also, Python uses a strange traceback construction system where an exception has no stack trace when initially raised, and each time it bubbles up through a stack frame, an additional frame record is added to the stack trace. (A record is also added for a `raise` with 1 or 2 arguments, but not 0 or 3, hence the difference in the previous paragraph.) Due to this traceback construction system, a traceback won't contain any information about frames the exception didn't propagate to, and unusual exception handling patterns can cause a traceback to look nothing like what the stack looked like at the point of the initial `raise`.

Comment: that works, can you please explain the difference between `raise ex` and just `raise`

Comment: @JamesLin: Answer expanded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had never got a chance to dig into this.